# How do I show my imported table (shp file for forest boundary) in google earth engine on the map?

Tags: google-earth-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9vs8.jpg)[enter image description here][2]

I trying to view my imported data on the google earth engines map, and I don't know what code I need to write.  I am trying to look at forest cover boundaries. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
Map.addLayer(table, {}, 'Loita forest')
```